# Items in recyclerView version higher than v7:23.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Each item in the recyclerView higher than v7.23.1.1 are shown separately. it means while scroling down each next one is on the next side.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"

    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleVolume"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBarInfoText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBarInfoText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:elevation="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material" />
```

my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'net.htmlparser.jericho:jericho-html:3.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTiFf.jpg)

Comment: can you post a pic of the issue? which LayoutManager are you using?

Comment: You should keep the versions the same, but I don't understand what you're asking. Maybe the problem is that you have `layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `layout_alignParentStart="false"` trying to compete for layout ordering

Comment: its the LinearLayoutManager. 

layout_alignParentStart doesnt matter. its only when i increase the version of the recyclerView from 23.1.1 upwards

picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/sTiFf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 23.2 from `SupportLibrary` introduced a new feature for `RecyclerView` which is auto-measurement which allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible.

So there is a warning in the release notes to check your `RecyclerView` items views.

> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.

See if this is your problem and check here for more information:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.eg/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html